# How to set state after data was fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I fetch data and want to set state with newly received data. I have a special function for data fetching (loadData) and a component(App) where I have to setState. However, I can't pass there data from loadData. When I write const res = loadData(), I get Pending...

```
async function loadData() {
    let query = `someQuery`;

    let url = 'someUrl',
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query     
        })
    };

const response = await fetch(url, options);
const body = await response.json();
return body.data   // I have to set this data to state
}

const App = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
      loadData(); // here I would like to setState. How to pass in here data 
      received as a result 
          of loadData?
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you get `Pending...`, because it's a `Promise`.

What do you do with a Promise?
You can append `.then(response => ...)` to it in this case, because you can't `await` inside `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {  
      loadData()  
          .then(response => setState(response.data.results));  
    }, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

`loadData` is an `async` function. That means, it returns `Promise`. In this case, you have to do `await loadData()` to access its result. Because function in `useEffect` can't be `async`, you have to wrap it in another function like this:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const wrappingFuncion = async () => {
            const res = await loadData();
            setState(res);
        }
        wrappingFunction();
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: You can't do that inside `useEffect`

Comment: Yes, not directly, but you can create an `async` wrapper function in it.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the person asking for help doesn't. So you can edit your answer to provide it.

Comment: ...and now you're not calling the wrapping function. See how `async/await` is unhelpful inside `useEffect`?